# Measuring 'data items accessed' by index technique to retrieve item (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan, btree

In the example I have attached, a btree is being used to search for the number 19. With PostgreSQL execution plan, buffers read/hit are being shown. Which would they be in the example I have attached?

I am pretty sure it is the nodes of the tree and not having much to do with the green arrows. In the number of pages used to make a search, I expect this to be 3. But in the case of data items accessed, I expect those to be 6 (green arrows as indication). How can I measure this latter statistic?

[image: btree example]